# How do I fix my smoke-emitting pizza stone?

Tags: baking, oven, pizza

I'm trying to cook "authentic" pizza in a home oven. The recipe I'm following asks that you preheat the oven to the highest it can get (500°F/260°C for me) with the stone inside. So, I follow this instruction. For the first 15 minutes, everything's fine. Then, I see liquid forming at the top of the stone. Soon enough, tons of smoke is coming out and I have to turn on the fan. I decided to abandon my plan to create the perfect pizza because of this problem with my stone.

I think the liquid coming out of the pizza stone is oil that's been absorbed from past times I've cooked with it. It wasn't a problem then because I didn't preheat my pizza stone previously and only cooked at 425°F/220°C. Then, the oil heats up and evaporates into smoke.

How can I fix the issue of oil coming out and smoking up everything when I'm preheating my stone at high temperatures?

Edit: Just found out that my mom puts oil on the stone every time she cooks pizza D:<

Comment: You shouldn't be oiling the stone.

Comment: @GdD it didn't occur to me that they were deliberately oiling it, because some toppings can give off quite a bit of oil and that can drip.  If it turns out they really were deliberately oiling it I'll delete my answer because there would be way too much smoke

Comment: Some people may think that you oil the stone to keep the pizzas from sticking, which isn't the right thing to do with a baking stone. Using cornmeal or coarse semolina is the way to go on that, but you may be right @ChrisH.

Comment: @GdD even flour is better than oil in domestic ovens that don't get too hot, though I use semolina by choice. But there are instructions out there for seasoning stones with oil (there are probably instructions for all sorts of far dumber ideas as well)

Comment: Semolina is much tastier isn't it @ChrisH, plus a nice crunch.

Comment: @GdD I amn't oiling the stone intentionally. I use a lot of olive oil in my pizza dough, so I assume that's where the oil is coming from. Also, I think cheese releases grease sometimes, and pepperoni and other meats are very greasy.

Comment: Start using less oil in your pizza dough.  If it's soaking into the stone, you're using way too much.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Just found out that my mom puts oil on the pizza stone every time she bakes pizza. That's my main problem

Comment: Well, you know the long-term solution, then.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to burn it off, but you can do it quite slowly, then it should be fine for future use.

Although 425°F (220°C) is rather cool for pizza, it's around the smoke point of many oils. But as you didn't preheat the stone when you used it at this low temperature, it probably never even got that hot (BTW you sound like you've learnt this by now, but if you're not going to preheat it, there's no point using a stone).

So you should probably start by putting it in a cold oven and turning on to 425°F. When that temperature has been reached and held for a good few minutes, and it's not smoking, increase by 25° and wait until it stops smoking. Keep going until you reach the maximum on the dial.

You can do all this on a day when you can ventilate well, not just before use. Alternatively it's not unknown to use pizza stones in barbecues, so you could try and burn it off outside, but without the temperature control.

If there's any chance that water could have soaked in, from even a brief dip or a wipe with a dripping wet cloth, start with a couple of hours not far below boiling point (say 80°C or 200°F) to dry it.

New stones are supposed to be baked with nothing on top before first use anyway. I think mine wanted the drying step when new as well.

Comment: I think this answer is valid even if the stone was deliberately oiled, it will just take longer to burn it off.

Comment: @GdD I'd definitely want to do as much as possible outside in that case, and bringing up the temperature gradually is probably mire important

Comment: @ChrisH Should I be burning off the oil after every time I make pizza? Is there a way to prevent oil from getting into the stone in the first place?

Comment: @SomeGuy that depends on where the oil is coming from. Pizza is crust on the bottom, and (classic) pizza crust dough doesn’t contain oil. So what went wrong?

Comment: @Sneftel I amn't oiling the stone intentionally. I use a lot of olive oil in my pizza dough, so I assume that's where the oil is coming from. Also, I think cheese releases grease sometimes, and pepperoni and other meats are very greasy

Comment: The fairly thin dough I most often bake on my stone is sourdough, with no oil at all; the other, rather fluffy, dough I make in the bread machine before rolling out, uses 1 tablespoon to 350g (~12 Oz) of flour, so not oily at all.  If you're using an oily dough, it might be worth looking at methods that part baking parchment on non-stick sheet on top of the stone (check temperature suitability for any particular product).  Some people do this for focaccia, for example.  That might also help if you want a generous amount of topping and little crust for a margin.

Comment: I reckon burn it off once to fix it, and solve the problem of getting loads of oil onto the stone.  Minor drips are dealt with by putting the stone (scrape off any spilt lumps of cheese) back in the hot oven as it cools, and preheating it next time.

Comment: Alternately, if the OP has a grill, that's a great place to burn the pizza stone clean.

Comment: @FuzzyChef grill as in barbecue (which I mentioned) or as in broiler (which is how I broke my last pizza stone making naan bread)? English vs. English!

Comment: As in BBQ.  That way all the smoke is outside.  Low heat, so you don't crack the stone.

Comment: @FuzzyChef thought so. I made a very good pizza in a kettle barbecue fired with charcoal and oak, but it was too much effort to make a habit of it. Even if used so gently it didn't get hot enough to finish the burn-off it would make a good start

Comment: Incidentally, the stone should be good up to like 600C.  What causes it to crack is *uneven* heat -- if the middle of the stone is 200C higher than the edges, it'll crack (or vice-versa).  That's why you need to be careful with the broiler or charcoal BBQs.

Comment: @Sneftel Found my problem, apparently my mom has been oiling the pizza stone every time she bakes pizza this whole time

Comment: @FuzzyChef yes, that's what killed mine - the naan shielded the middle from direct heat and cooled it, so even though the whole thing was preheated it cracked.